# UITabBarController w/ Multiple MKMapViews

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I have a `UITabBarController` controlling a couple `MKMapViews`.  How would I keep their state persistent with one another?  I've tried setting up a singleton pattern, but they are still independent.

Comment: What do you mean with "state persistent"? Do you want to have the same region in all your MKMapView? So when Tab A regions changed, then you'd like to also change the Tab B region?

Comment: Yes!  Any change to one will influence the other.  Same annotations, same region, same span, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible solutions for your problem

1. You instantiate one (1x) `MKMapView` in a controller (maybe a singleton). Let's say in your `AppDelegate` you have one `MKMapView` instance.

   - You use a `UIViewController` instance per Tab (so: many UIViewControllers but only one MKMapView in a controller.
   - You listen for `- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` at your tabbar controller delegate.
   - when the user changes the tab, you place the single (1x) `MKMapView` on the appearing UIViewController's view.
   - But here you will have the same content (Annotations, Regions, data at all)
2. You can synchronize many `MKMapView`

   - Listen for MKMapView delegates (`– mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:`, etc.) and synchronize the values to you other MKMapViews. You need to do that by Notifications (`NSNotification`) or by a controller.
   - this would give you more flexibility which values you'd like to sync and which values must be different from `MKMapView` to `MKMapView`.

Comment: Thanks man!  I was halfway through implementing 1) but I couldn't remember what delegate messages to listen for.  2) looks like a more elegant solution though so I'll go with that.